# Emogies support on IOS, Android, Website

Tags: php, android, ios, web-services, encode

I am working on one App Which is on IOS, Android and We have Website also for the same. In app we have provided one functionality as user can add comment in form of Emogies also. Now when user added emogies from android device we are unable to Display them in IOS app as well as Website and vice versa. 
How we can recover this as emogie entered from any Platform(Android/IOS) should be display on all platform. 
How Whatsapp has recover this issue any idea?
Can anyone have solution for this please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Both android and ios support emoji with the same codes. I think you might have a problem on the server side. Perhaps your database doesn't support full UTF8.

For example, in mysql tables must be encoded in utf8mb4 instead of utf8. See https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4.